# Orderby location a nested query with parse (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, nested, nssortdescriptor

I currently face an annoying issue whilst working on an iphone app (iOS 8).
Basically here is the situation:
I use Parse for my database. I created a TableViewController inheriting from PFQueryTableViewController.
Now I am populating this Tableview through overwriting the queryForTable Method. In there I try to orderby distance with a nested query. It is actually exactly the same question like here [Parse Question](https://parse.com/questions/orderby-distance-in-nested-object-geopoint-query-on-ios):

> How can i orderBy distance? When i do this query the results are ordered by the Offer, but i would like to order by distance of Restaurant (the Restaurant is a pointer in the Offer).

As you can see, below Hector answered to use NSSortDescriptor to sort it, but I cannot figure it out how to do that. Would someone be so kind and make an example. My code looks quite similar to this one:

```
PFGeoPoint *geopoint = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLocation:location];
PFQuery *position = [Restaurant createQueryForNetwork];
[position whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:geopoint withinKilometers:3];

PFQuery *pfq = [Offer createQueryForNetwork];
[pfq includeKey:@"restaurant"];
[pfq whereKey:@"restaurant" matchesQuery:position];
pfq.limit = 12;

[self findAllInBackground:pfq withBlock:block];
```

I hope it is clear what I mean, otherwise let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I understood I have to do that in objectsDidLoad? Can anyone help, please?